# Include a button on toolstrip under a tab control

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

When I assign the button on toolstrip in a tab control, the application just stands by and will not respond.  Here is my code:

```
    ToolStrip toolStrip_3 = new ToolStrip();
    toolStrip_3.setWidth100();
    toolStrip_3.setHeight("20px");
    toolStrip_3.setReverseOrder(true);

    ToolStripButton button = new ToolStripButton(CONSTANTS.notesAddButton_title());
    toolStrip_3.addButton(button);
    conflictLayout.addMember(toolStrip_3);
```

When I comment out this line:

```
//conflictLayout.addMember(toolStrip_3);
```

the application works without problems.

Comment: Can you post a standlaone case so that I can also generate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
toolStrip_3.setHeight(20);
```

instead of :

```
toolStrip_3.setHeight("20px");
```